# Leaflet coordinates wrapping

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

If I zoom far away and see the world multiples times, when I click somewhere near the edge a mouse click event is fired with some insane coordinates like `[32, 500]`. To get the real coordinates I have to use `event.latlng.wrap()`. Is there any way to enable wrapping by default, so I don't have to do it everywhere manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: nope.

It's not implemented and trying to override default latLng behavior would break some parts of Leaflet code.